# PoolableConnectionFactory: Fail to convert between UTF8 and UCS2: failUTF8Conv

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am facing this issue while connecting to an Oracle database:

> org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (Fail to convert between UTF8 and UCS2:
>   failUTF8Conv)

Why, and how can I resolve this?

Comment: That type of error is usually related to a character set issue, the character set the data is stored in the database is different from how its read. You may want to use a more native format for reading the data such as getBytes() and/or change the character encoding for the system.

Comment: You should also use the updated correct driver (jar) file to connect to the database, it might also resolve the issue